# Windows port will not open in google compute engine

Tags: networking, chef, google-compute-engine, telnet

I've added a firewall rule in `GCE` `udp:5585;tcp:5585` in my networking config.

I've also added an `inbound rule` in Windows to accept both udp and tcp connections on port 5585. I'm trying to set this up for Chef. However,  when trying to telnet,

I get a connection refused error. I run `netstat -a` in powershell on the remote VM and I don't see the port.

I'm out of options. What could possibly be the problem ?

Comment: If netstat doesn't show that port in the listening state then nothing is listening on that port. You need to investigate why that is.

Comment: @joeqwerty fair enough. WinRM quickconfig command in powershell fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing was listening on 5585. Running `WinRM quickconfig` fixed the issue when pasting into powershell. This added some special firewall rule and began listening on that port and fixed my chef problem.

Comment: You should accept your answer as well.